# Hide Billing Address field in stripe flutter payment sheet

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate stripe payment system in my flutter app.
After successful payment the user will receive in-app currency (which basically eliminates the need of anyone specifying the billing address).
Is there a way to remove this billing address field from the `paymentSheet` form? I think this field will cause confusion among users. Or should I try a different payment system?

Answer (score 0):

The billing details are for completing the payment, not delivery of goods and many payment methods require some billing fields to be collected. By default, the Payment Sheet collects the required details automatically.

You can adjust this configuration ([Android](https://stripe.dev/stripe-android/paymentsheet/com.stripe.android.paymentsheet/-payment-sheet/-billing-details-collection-configuration/-address-collection-mode/index.html), [iOS](https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/stripepaymentsheet/documentation/stripepaymentsheet/paymentsheet/billingdetailscollectionconfiguration/addresscollectionmode)), but then you'd be responsible for providing the required billing details for the selected payment method type.

I'm not sure if/how these configuration options are supported or exposed for any community Flutter packages, you'd need to check with the developer of the package for that information.

Comment: I understand, but if I collected the billing address details beforehand, I want to remove the field in the form regardless. I've seen plenty of apps where its not required (and most of the users wouldn't know what to input). 
P.S there is also a flutter sdk from stripe, it's not a community package, but I couldn't find a way to omit that field

Comment: I linked to the configuration that allows suppressing billing details collection in the PaymentSheet, but you still need to pass the values you collected previously when confirming payment. Stripe does not maintain any Flutter SDK I'm aware of -- there are only community libraries. Can you link to the one you're using?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's just a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe) from verified publisher. What do you mean, what configuration? I achieved suppressing by using `CardForm` widget and passing false for postal code and it doesn't request selecting a country. Can you show me what you meant in your comment?

Comment: I linked to the structure for the `BillingDetailsCollectionConfiguration` in the two native SDKs. You can see an example at the top here: https://stripe.dev/stripe-android/paymentsheet/com.stripe.android.paymentsheet/-payment-sheet/-billing-details-collection-configuration/index.html

This let's you disable automatic billing details collection when a payment method requires them, but then you need to provide those yourself when confirming.